# Why check for nil in init()

Tags: go

I'm reading [this article](https://elithrar.github.io/article/approximating-html-template-inheritance/) which offers this code in its example:

```
var templates map[string]*template.Template

// Load templates on program initialisation
func init() {
    if templates == nil {
        templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
    }
```

Why check for `if templates == nil` in `init()`? Won't it always be the same at this point in execution?

Comment: Could be a cut and paste from somewhere else into init.

Comment: @ZanLynx: That's as good as any guess I can come up with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to check for nil in the code provided in the article. There are other ways to structure the code.

Option 1:

```
var templates = map[string]*template.Template{}

func init() {
    // code following the if statement from the function in the article
}
```

Option 2:

```
var templates = initTemplates()

func initTemplates() map[string]*template.Template{} {
    templates := map[string]*template.Template{}
    // code following the if statement from the function in the article
    return templates
}
```

Option 3:

```
func init() {
    templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
    // code following the if statement from the function in the article
}
```

You will see all of these approaches in Go code. I prefer the second option because it makes it clear that `templates` is initialized in the function `initTemplates`.  The other options require some looking around to find out where `templates` is initialized.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad to know my understanding of init() wasn't off.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Package initialization](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization)
>
> Variables may also be initialized using functions named `init`
>   declared in the package block, with no arguments and no result
>   parameters.
>
> ```
> func init() { … }
> ```
>
> Multiple such functions may be defined, even within a single source
>   file.

Now or in the future there may be multiple `init` functions in the package. For example,

```
package plates

import "text/template"

var templates map[string]*template.Template

// Load project templates on program initialisation
func init() {
    if templates == nil {
        templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
    }
    // Load project templates
}

// Load program templates on program initialisation
func init() {
    if templates == nil {
        templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
    }
    // Load program templates
}
```

Programs should have zero bugs. Program defensively.